# SUMPRODUCT Formula is throwing an error Formula Parse Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created below formula instead of `SUMIFS` because arrays do not work with `Google sheets` `SUMIFS` function so i used google to make this fomrula but i am getting an error `Formula Parse Error`

Your help will be much appreciated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('3. Emp. Leave Setup'!B:B=B2:B)*('3. Emp. Leave Setup'!F:F>=DATEVALUE('Yearly Clndr'!E2:E))*('3. Emp. Leave Setup'!G:G<=DATEVALUE('Yearly Clndr'!F2:F)),'3. Emp. Leave Setup'!J:J*0)
```

Here is `SUMIFS` formula which is working fine but unable to convert it into Arrays

```
=SUMIFS('3. Emp. Leave Setup'!J:J,'3. Emp. Leave Setup'!B:B,B2,'3. Emp. Leave Setup'!F:F,">="&'Yearly Clndr'!E2,'3. Emp. Leave Setup'!G:G,"<="&'Yearly Clndr'!F2)
```

Comment: Simply fixing the syntax of the formula may not get you the results you want. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75384548/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Alright give me a moment to update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get row-by-row results, one result per each value in the range `B2:B10`, use `map()`, like this:

```
=map( 
  B2:B10, 
  lambda( 
    value, 
    sumifs( 
      '3. Emp. Leave Setup'!J:J, 
      '3. Emp. Leave Setup'!B:B, value, 
      '3. Emp. Leave Setup'!F:F, ">=" & 'Yearly Clndr'!E2, 
      '3. Emp. Leave Setup'!G:G, "<=" & 'Yearly Clndr'!F2 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to add condition like if column `G2:G="Specific Value"` then Paste result i did but its not working by adding `=map(IF(G2:G="Specific Value", B2:B, ""), lambda(value, sumifs(.....`

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Show a table of sample data together with your desired results from that data.